# How to send different requests according to checkbox in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I've got a checkbox with filtering, e.g.:

if false => display all data (one endpoint in API)
if true => display only filtered data (another endpoint)

I struggle with sending different requests like this

```
<template>
  <div>

        <div style="display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;">
        <div class="col-md-9">

        <b-form-checkbox v-model="my__specialization" 
                         value=true
                         unchecked-value=false
                         @change="filterOrdersSpec()"
                         >Show filtered</b-form-checkbox> 

        <p>{{ my__specialization }}</p>

      </div>
    </div>

<div v-for="el in APIData" :key="el.id" >
</div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'Orders',
    data () {
      return {
          APIData: [],
          my__specialization: false,

        }
    },

    methods: {

        filterOrdersSpec() {
            if (this.my__specialization) {
            axios
            .get('/api/v1/filter-orders/specs')
            .then(response => {
              this.APIData = response.data.results
            })
          }
          else {          
          axios
          .get('/api/v1/orders/get')
          .then(response => {
            this.APIData = response.data.results
          })
          }
        
    }, 
  },

    created () {
          axios
          .get('/api/v1/orders/get')
          .then(response => {
            this.APIData = response.data.results
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })   
    },


}
</script>
```

This construction does filter Data on setting checkbox to TRUE, but when setting FALSE, the request to filter is sent again. The question is - why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of the problem : `this.my__specialization` returning boolean as a string `"true"`/`"false"`. Hence, `if (this.my__specialization) { ... }` condition will always return true as it consider the value as string instead of boolean.

Solution **:** You have to convert the string value into a boolean.

```
if (this.my__specialization === "true") {
}
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({  
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      APIData: null,
      my__specialization: false  
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterOrdersSpec() {
      this.APIData = (this.my__specialization === "true") ? 'Endpoint 1' : 'Endpoint 2';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox
      v-model="my__specialization"
      value="true"
      unchecked-value="false"
      @input="filterOrdersSpec()"
    >Show filtered</b-form-checkbox>
    <div>my__specialization: <strong>{{ my__specialization }}</strong></div>
  <div>APIData: <strong>{{ APIData }}</strong></div>
</div>
```